# R keep rows where all values are < a threshold

Tags: r, rows, subset

I have a data.frame with 19 columns and 2000+ rows. Column 1 is the dependent variable, and columns V1:V17 independent variables. I would like to keep only the rows where the value for EVERY independent variable listed is between 0 and 0.30. However, each row has a varying number of independent variable values. Non-values are filled with NA, but I want to more or less "ignore" the NA values.

Sample data layout:
[image]

Reproducible sample:

```
> dfY <- structure(list(formula_vec1 = structure(c(9L, 3L, 12L, 6L, 11L, 
5L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 10L, 4L), .Label = c("BQbinary10BQBAPA ~ BedrockGrouped", 
"BQbinary10BQBAPA ~ FlowCategory2", "BQbinary10BQBAPA ~ MixedForBinary", 
"BQbinary10BQBAPA ~ SurfGeoCode", "BQbinary10BQBAPA ~ WetBinary", 
"BQbinary10BQBAPA ~ WetForBinary", "BQbinary10TPA ~ BedrockGrouped", 
"BQbinary10TPA ~ FlowCategory2", "BQbinary10TPA ~ MixedForBinary", 
"BQbinary10TPA ~ SurfGeoCode", "BQbinary10TPA ~ WetBinary", "BQbinary10TPA ~ WetForBinary"
), class = "factor"), `(Intercept)` = c(0.273438838044101, 0.706417333314839, 
0.827323681408328, 0.827323681408328, 0.670245265976437, 1, 0.293077765083469, 
0.0729824051982314, 1, 0.178457442476982, 0.998548313507269, 
0.998548313507378), SlopeMIN = c(0.189866676669654, 0.654211112307992, 
0.544287209863837, 0.544287209863837, 0.994937849813948, 0.999999999999999, 
0.191210657045005, 0.03858791129829, 0.994491578112418, 0.994856875070902, 
0.997947006402924, 0.997947006406413), V3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0.132226649521136, 0.997947006402968, 0.999999999999613
), V4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.818915198441539, 
0.0971466407595114, 1, 0.997629408064154), V5 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.999999999999979, 0.997947006406465
), V6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.999999999999999, 
0.997947006406414), V7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.998510413314225, 0.998586213707042), V8 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.999999999999999, 0.997947006406413
), V9 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    V10 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), V11 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), V12 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), V13 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), V14 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), V15 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), V16 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), V17 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), V18 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), .Names = c("formula_vec1", 
"(Intercept)", "SlopeMIN", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", 
"V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", 
"V18"), row.names = 9:20, class = "data.frame")
```

Intended output (kept only rows where ALL independent variables were <0.300):
[image]

In this small subset only values in V1 are <0.300, but there are other rows in the full data.frame that have multiple variables that meet the criteria.

I've tried using minimum values to extract the rows that I want, but that only gets the minimum value in each row, where I need ALL values to be <0.300.

I also tried subsetting the data, but I'm getting hung up with the NA values:

> dfOutput <- dfInput[dfInput[,3:19]>0.00000001 | dfInput[,3:19]<0.300, ]

Any ideas on where to go from here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible example. Screenshots if data are not very helpful.

Comment: I've tried, but every time I use dput on a small subset in R, I get the structure for the ENTIRE data.frame. If you have suggestions on how to pull code for just a small subset, I'd love to know how.

Comment: `dput(dfInput[1:20, 1:20])` You should play around with the `or` statement that you are trying to subset by *before* subsetting. and then if you only want *all* `TRUE` for each row, use `all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
dfOutput <- dfInput[apply(dfInput[,3:19]>0.00000001 & dfInput[,3:19]<0.300, 1, all, na.rm=TRUE),  ]
```

And now for a reproducible example, I'll explain what is going on:

```
# data
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:3, NA, 3:1), y=c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, 2, 3))
# this returns a matrix!
df[, 1:2] > 2
# use apply
apply(df[, 1:2] > 2, 1, all)
# "ignore" NA's
apply(df[, 1:2] > 2, 1, all, na.rm=TRUE)
# finally you do
df[apply(df[, 1:2] > 2, 1, all, na.rm=TRUE), ]
```

Comment: I just tried running this, and ended up with an output data.frame identical to my input data.frame; no rows were removed. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your condition is larger than 0.00001 OR smaller than 0.3. My guess is that most numbers will fit that condition. Perhaps you mean `&` instead of `|`.

Comment: I was looking for AND, not OR, sorry! I want ALL values to fall between 0 and 0.30. I changed the | to &, and it ran perfectly!